# I can't get the answer proper answer in my Android Calculator

Tags: java, android, calculator

I had follow the steps to create my Calculator Apps, while I pressed 100+6%, it should be 106.0 but it showed me the final calculated answer was 100.06, is there something I missed? Thank you.

```
       Equal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            process = Callayout.getText().toString();

            process = process.replaceAll("%","/100");
            process = process.replaceAll("x","*");
            process = process.replaceAll("(6%)","*0.06");

            Context rhino = Context.enter();

            rhino.setOptimizationLevel(-1);

            String finalans = "";

            try{
                Scriptable scriptable = rhino.initStandardObjects();
                finalans = rhino.evaluateString(scriptable,process,"Javascript",1,null).toString();
            }catch(Exception e){
                finalans = "0";
            }

            Callayout.setText(finalans);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to StackOverflow (SO). Looking at your code, your line `process = process.replaceAll("%","/100");` suggests that the results you are seeing (100.06) is correct, since you're putting in `100 + (6/100)`. Why do you expect to see 106.0 as your answer?

Comment: Thank you very much, if I wanna to do as 100+6%=106, how should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The `/` operator takes precedence over `+`. The expression you entered is equal to `100+(6/100)`. Also, you don't need this line: `process = process.replaceAll("(6%)","*0.06");`, because all the `%` have already been replaced.

Comment: If I want to do 100+(100*(6/100)), how should I edit the equation?